# Selenium find hidden element C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have specific situation, from Inspect element in Google Chrome I have this:

```
 <span class="markup--quote markup--p-quote is-other" name="anon_7ee3d25bf521" data-creator-ids="anon">If what you care about&#8202;—&#8202;or are trying to report on&#8202;—&#8202;is impact on the world, it all gets very slippery. You’re not measuring a rectangle, you’re measuring a multi-dimensional space. You have to accept that things are very imperfectly measured and just try to learn as much as you can from multiple metrics and anecdotes.</span>
```

I want get text based on `data-creator-ids="anon"` but problem is when I click View Page source this is totally hidden.

I try this:

```
IWebElement ell = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[data-creator-ids='anon']"));

            MessageBox.Show(ell.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Problem:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=no such element: Unable to locate
>   element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"[data-creator-ids='anon']"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=48.0.2564.116)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459
>   (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 10.0
>   x86_64)   Source=WebDriver

I also tried by Class Name but same problem.
Is there any trick to get this text?

Also I have one button with same problem, I only need Id but button is totally hidden from html source:

```
<button class="button button--chromeless" data-action="select-anchor" data-action-value="3331">Top highlight</button>
```

Comment: Is the element in question always a span?

Comment: Yes it is always span

Comment: is the element loaded with ajax ? maybe you need to add some `wait` before locating the element

Comment: I tried out both the solutions given in answers, both working for me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at [this interesting post](http://ddavison.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html), you'll notice that you need to define an element type when using CSS-Selectors:

```
element[attribute(*|^|$|~)='value']
```

Based upon this, all you have to do is add the correct element to your selector; in your case a span element:

```
IWebElement ell = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[data-creator-ids='anon']"));
MessageBox.Show(ell.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

So instead of `"[data-creator-ids='anon']"` you should use `"span[data-creator-ids='anon']"`. This should yield the correct result.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span[data-creator-ids='anon']"}

Comment: LINK: view-source:https://medium.com/@ev/a-mile-wide-an-inch-deep-48f36e48d4cb#.nsl64ehml

Comment: There is no element on the page which has the data-creator-ids=anon attribute....

Comment: Yes, no in html source but you can see it in inspect element from Google Chrome.

Comment: Even using a simple document.getElementsByTagName doesn't show the span is present. Nor could I find it using Chromes Inspect Element...

Comment: I want get this text http://prntscr.com/adsze7 Thank you for help, I appreciate it.

Comment: My given solution should work. The issue might lie in the time you're giving Selenium to find the element. Try extending the time a bit.

Answer (score -1):

it may be better to try to get by XPath, rather than CSSSelector. This may well take you a step closer:

```
IWebElement ell = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@data-creator-ids='anon']"));
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@data-creator-ids='anon']"}

Comment: LINK: view-source:https://medium.com/@ev/a-mile-wide-an-inch-deep-48f36e48d4cb#.nsl64ehml

Comment: will get back to you in an hour -school run :). viewed the page source. `data-creator-ids` wasn't present -back soon...

Comment: lol -or not (based on the sneaky -1 vote).. har har har!! (e4xplode) :-)